# Linking tomcat with external folder of system but unable to find files inside the tomcat directory

Tags: java, tomcat, symlink, tomcat9

I have linked the tomcat server with external folder by changing in server.xml file

When I hit URL : http://localhost:8080/files/
It gives me all list of files and folders in URL which is mapped with external folder but I want to access file inside my java class.
I can find the folder name FILES inside \apache-tomcat-9.0.33\work\Catalina\localhost\files
but unable to find any files and folder inside it.

Also added below line in context.xml file

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to access .class file in the browser?

Comment: No, I am trying to access and read JSON file.